# PHP, Actionscript Object Oriented Programming Design Pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, actionscript, oop

I was wondering how to do the PHP OOP design pattern for real life application. I wish someone can share their learning experience with me. I am particular interested in PHP and actionscript. Most of the books I could find in the book store are only basic PHP (or AS3) programming. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Please do not close this topic..I am so desperate to know the answer since no one around me can help me about the topic. Stackoverflow is the best forum that many experts always help people when someone needs it.

Comment: if you understand SO, and you do, don't mix things. PHP and AS/AS3 are different things and, as such, should be asked separately.

Comment: I understand they are two different things. I was asking if someone from two different fields could give me some advises. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but on the last couple Actionscript 3 projects I've developed I have used a combination of [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) and [AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) with great results. I am a PHP novice but know AS3 well. Hooking up a proxy to a AMFPHP service was pretty straightforward and using commands and notifications worked well.

If you're new to Actionscript or PureMVC you can find project skeletons that will help get you started.

Comment: cool..I was wondering if you can post your project link so I can see your works? I used AMFPHP with Flex before not PureMVC. It will be so helpful for me to see your projects. Thanks a million!

Comment: Thanks knuckfubuck...it is a nice project. Did you finish it alone or with your team? just curious.....

Comment: I was the sole Flash developer but there was a team of people including another web developer who did the html and php work.

Answer (score 2):

I felt that *PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice* by Zandstra  (ISBN13: 978-1430229254, ISBN10: 143022925X) was one of the most effective books when it came to upping my game in PHP. It covers patterns pretty extensively with some real world examples and clear explanations.